# transfer data from device to mac

Tags: object, bluetooth, iobluetooth

Good Evening to all,

I am trying to implement bluetooth functionality through which user will be able to send data (data can be image or video) from device to mac or desktop. After googling I found  code from [www.pocketmagic.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Bluetooth-iOS-Code.zip](http://www.pocketmagic.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Bluetooth-iOS-Code.zip)

In this, device get paired with the mac bluetooth which is enable at the time. But I didn't get any method through which user can transfer file on mac.

If someone knows how to send file from device to mac please give me some solution.

Thanks in advance.